# How to test Symfony standalone bundle

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have developped some bundles i.e. https://github.com/975L/EmailBundle and I want to add tests for them. So, I have created the file `Tests/Service/EmailServiceTest.php` that contains  one test.

I have installed phpunit using `sudo apt install phpunit` on my Ubuntu computer, but when I `cd` to my bundle's folder and run `phpunit` I have the following error:

> 1)
>   c975L\EmailBundle\Tests\Service\EmailServiceTest::testCreateEmailObject
>   Error: Class 'c975L\EmailBundle\Service\EmailService' not found

It looks like the autoload can't find the class, even if declared at the top with `use`.

I saw some solutions over the web that requires to create a `bootstrap.php` with autoload but even with this, it doesn't work...

So my question is **how do we test a standalone Symfony Bundle with phpunit?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good idea to install phpunit on a per project basis, as version differences could come up if you have multiple projects.

(1) `composer require phpunit/phpunit --dev`

> I saw some solutions over the web that requires to create a bootstrap.php with autoload but even with this, it doesn't work...

You can use composer's autoloader as a bootstrap. A custom bootstrap might come in handy in some cases, but not necessary.

(2) Create a `phpunit.xml.dist` file, something like this (your current one does not specify a bootstrap):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="MyBundle test suite">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./Tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory>./</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory>./Resources</directory>
            <directory>./Tests</directory>
            <directory>./vendor</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
</phpunit>
```

Also check out `vendor/bin/phpunit --generate-configuration` which is nice.

(3) Run `vendor/bin/phpunit`

It should find the config file automatically, but you can also specify it with the `--configuration` option

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In fact all dependencies have to be installed in the `vendor` folder of the bundle, as for a full symfony application. As it was a standalone bundle I was thinking it was not needed. Is it right?

Comment: If your bundle uses them, they are needed :) It can be a bit tricky to figure out. Since this is a bundle, having the framework-bundle as a dependency is OK, but you can also use just what you really need, like config, DI, etc.

Comment: Thanks! It works! The class is now found, but I'm facing a new problem. As I use the type-hinting to inject services in classes, it works when using the bundle but not with the test. As you seem to know about testing, can you lead me to an help link about this? Otherwise I will look through the web.

Comment: Symfony DI is injecting services, and you don't have that here. You should not create instances of these deps though. It is a longer topic, read up on phpunit mocking. It is not too hard, but it may take some time to get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

At present, there is no comprehensive and clear documentation on how to conduct functional tests for standalone Symfony bundles.

To gain insight into this, you can examine some Symfony bundles to understand their approaches:

https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/tree/3.x/Tests

It is relative complicated and messy by my humble opinion.

Recently, Symfony released new conventions on how to write bundles. For example, the current recommendations suggest placing code in the 'src/' directory. However, all core Symfony bundles like "security bindle" still have code in the root, making everything even messier.

I wrote an article where I proposed my way how to do it with clean way:

https://medium.com/@fico7489/symfony-functional-tests-for-standalone-bundles-9666045a2309

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'll have a look